Difference in modelling between transforming the response and using a non-normal distribution?
In regression modeling, what is the difference between fitting a model by transforming the response variable (e.g., applying a log transformation to y) and then backtransforming the outputs to the original scale, versus specifying a non-normal distribution for the response (e.g., using a log-normal distribution)?
How do these approaches affect the interpretation, accuracy and predictions of the model?
Example using brms:
# Log-transformed model
fit_log_transformed <- brm(log(y) ~ x, data = mydata, family = gaussian())
# We then backtransform the output to the original scale

# Log-normal model
fit_lognormal <- brm(y ~ x, data = mydata, family = lognormal())
```r


Your two examples explicitly look like different types of regression: in the first, y has an exponential relationship with x but in the second it has a linear relation (if my assumptions about brm are correct).

@PBulls yes, that previous post indeed answers my question. Thanks!
